# Can't find Camera Stage in Cinema 4D R18

Tags: camera, stage, cinema-4d

I can't find the Camera Stage option for Cinema 4D R18.

It is not on the Camera menu.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow. In it's current form the question is about using the Cinema 4D interface that is off topic and might be better suited for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). If your question about programming/scripting C4D (with the c++ API/C.O.F.F.E.E. or Python APIs) the Camera Stage then that would be better suited for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the Menu: "Create" > "Environment" > Stage